# Wordpress featured image url rendering incorrectly when page is loaded causing image to break

Tags: post-thumbnails

I migrated a site from my testing server to the live server. Everything transferred normally only the featured images are broken and not displaying. The URL's are being rendered incorrectly even if i re-upload the image.

the testing server is  dave-conner.com

the live server is qmpdirect.com

the page where the issue is happening on is http://qmpdirect.com/cpap-kits/

the first image path should be:

qmpdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sleepstyle600-37440_184x184.jpg

but is instead rendering as:

/home/content/28/9036828/html//wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sleepstyle600-37440_184x184.jpg

If anyone can tell me why this is happening and how i can fix it I would greatly appreciate it. I have been banging my head against the wall for a while now.

Comment: You likely just used an incorrect path in your template file. Can you pastebin your template file?

Comment: I didnt specify any path. I just uploaded the featured image through the wordpress dashboard. And these images are working fine on the testing server. If you would like me to post something I will but i didnt modify the template file.

Comment: I would like to see the template file. I think something might be wonky in there.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GMD7svzx

This is the template file of the page that im having the issues with. Let me know if there is anything else I can provide. Thanks for your help. Been at this for days now.

Comment: I think we are on the right path. There is a function, print_thumbnail, that is printing the images. Can you post the function definition? It is not in that file.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2YjaiJ2j

here is the print_thumbnail function

Comment: Can you also show me get_thumbnail?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mKkExTpU

get_thumbnail

Comment: So...there is so crazy things going on here. I will probably keep asking for function defs. Basically, there is something within the theme that is changing the path. My guess is that it's not standard. Is this a public theme you are using or a custom one?

Comment: This is a custom theme. I dont get why the image paths would change just my migrating the site.

Comment: Have you tried the solution found in this thread: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851075/wp-print-thumbnail-function-is-not-working)

Comment: just tried it but no luck. This is really odd. I have done this a dozen times and dont get why it would put this url. Especially with the double //. Still need help if anyone is familiar with this issue.

Comment: Dont know why it wont let me comment anymore so i had to put comment as an aswer

Comment: You must use the same account for comments as you have used for the question. Now you have two accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at the database.

1) check the upload_path option and correct directly if needed *(well, this one can be altered here too: wp-admin/options.php)*

```
SELECT *  FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` = 'upload_path'
```

2) check the guid of the attachments and use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace) if needed

```
SELECT guid,post_mime_type  FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'attachment'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The location of the temporary files in the database was still set to the absolute hosting path of the old server. Once i changed this to the absolute hosting path of the live server the problem was corrected. I'm still not sure why this caused the image to break since wordpress moves these images to permanent folders but...problem solved. Thanks for everyone that offered suggestions. This is the only forum that even offered help. Thanks.